# Can I use pex for this connection between the shower and the tub faucet?

Tags: plumbing, pex

Can I use pex from my shower valve to my tub drop ear elbow?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you think you can do this? From everything I see right now, sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But there's an important caveat here. The other connectors are using Sharkbites, which are push connectors. The two in your picture are a compression fitting. You'll either want a [crimp ring](http://www.sharkbite.com/product/crimp-rings/) or a [clamp ring](http://www.sharkbite.com/product/clamps-rings/) to secure the pex to the fitting. These might require a special tool. You might also get away with using a regular screw clamp.